# Bootcamp assistant won't let me increase the Windows partition

Tags: bootcamp, windows, ssd, disk-utility

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on my Mac. The Bootcamp Assistant won't let me increase the Windows partiton's size above ~45 GB. I've got 200 GB free out of 500 GB on my SSD.

I run Disk Repair, but that didn't help. Do I have to buy iDefrag and defrag my disk, or are there other options (besides reinstalling OS X from a backup)?

Comment: It would be interesting to see a picture of the actual partition layout. Can you screenshot it from _Disk Utility.app_?

Answer (score 1):

I think alimack is right, has to do with contiguous space.  I resolved without purchasing idefrag.   Heres how.  In my case I had a 250gb drive and was only using about 50gb.   Boot camp was only allowing me to create a 125gb partition for windows.   I accepted that and partitioned the drive in boot camp. Before installing windows I rebooted the Mac OS, went into Disk Utilities and then deleted the windows partition.  Now start again and run bootcamp and you will find a lot more space is available for your windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem for me was that the bootcamp manager only allowed me to take up space from allocated partitions.

Go into Disk Utility, select your 500GB SSD and select the "Partition" tab.
Make sure that "Macintosh HD" is taking up all the 500GB.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen exactly the same problem, and solved it with iDefrag, the partitioning tool needs contiguous space, not just space.  The only other option is to wipe the drive.  There are other defrag tools but they're not as good.
I think iDefrag is the best available option (assuming you're using a standard HDD, don't defrag solid state drives)